# LARGE function with duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel

Am using LARGE function to get the ageing defects from excel. am getting like below:
[image: table]

In my case, I have two defects which having same date created. So I need to take the first 51 day's defect( DEF-2) and the second 51 day's defect( DEF-10). But currently am getting the first occurrence of 51. Please let me know how to get the multiple values for the single large value.

Comment: What is your current formula? What is exactly your expected output?

Comment: am using large(array,1). array= the ageing number( ex: 20,24,30 etc ...). and am giving 1,2,3 for first,second,third large values.

Comment: that formula gives 51, and not DEF-2 and DEF-10 what you described. Without clearly explaining your situation we can't help:(

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:
`=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(LARGE($A$2:$A$6,ROW(A1)),$A$2:$A$6,0))`
and drag it down
B2:B6 is the column of DEFFECT_ID change it to correspond your data but keep $
A2:A6 is the column of Days change it to corespond your data and keep $
Row (A1)=1 for Large(array,1) and when you drag it to second row it will become row(A2)=2
Match will find the row number (0 for exact match)
Index will return the Value in DEFFECT_ID